# Is this kind of borrowing the "Rust way"?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

When I try to start another application, write some stuff on it's stdin and then wait for it so finish, my code looks something like this (old_io):

```
let mut process = Command::new("example_app")
.arg("test").spawn().ok().expect("Failed.");

{
    let mut std = &mut process.stdin.as_mut().unwrap();
    std.write_all(input_example);
}

let output = process.wait_with_output().ok().expect("Failed.");
```

That's working, but I don't feel like that's the way to go. Since "&mut process.stdin.as_mut().unwrap()" seems to borrow "process", I need to make sure that it goes out of scope before accessing it again, don't I? And another question is: Why does it need to borrow "process" at all?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does it need to borrow "process" at all?"

Because you are using [`Option::as_mut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut). The signature looks like:

```
fn as_mut<'r>(&'r mut self) -> Option<&'r mut T>
```

This says that the lifetime of the return value is tied to the input. Additionally, it's a mutable reference, which you are only allowed to have one of at a particular time (to prevent *aliasing*).

The reason you need to add a new scope is because [borrow scopes are lexically-scoped](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6393). This is considered an annoying but work-aroundable issue. Right now, the mutable borrow lasts until the end of the block, which prevents borrowing `process` a second time.

In Vladimir's example:

```
process.stdin.as_mut().unwrap().write_all(input_example);
```

The borrow from `as_mut` is never stored in a variable, so it "goes out of scope" immediately after that line ends. This allows you to borrow it again without the need for a new scope.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you decided that you need an explicit borrow here. The following works perfectly:

```
use std::old_io::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let mut process = Command::new("tr")
        .arg("a-z").arg("A-Z")
        .spawn()
        .ok().expect("Failed.");

    let input_example = "hello world".as_bytes();

    process.stdin.as_mut().unwrap().write_all(input_example);

    let output = process.wait_with_output().ok().expect("Failed.");
    println!("Output:");
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8(output.output).unwrap());
}
```